# Ring loses shape on rotation in android kitkat

Tags: android

I am creating a circular progress bar using the following link :
http://mrigaen.blogspot.in/2013/12/create-circular-progress-bar-in-android.html

Now to set progress from the bottom, we are rotating the progress bar using the rotate animation. This works fine in android 4.1.1 ( please see the screenshot)
[image]

However when the run the same on android kitkat 4.4.2 , i get the following result
[image]

Please help... why is this happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it with two rings in a list (one of them is transparent). I don't actually know why but it works!

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadius="80dp"
        android:thickness="6dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
   </shape>
</item>
     <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadius="80dp"
        android:thickness="6dp"
        android:useLevel="false"
        >

        <gradient
          android:centerColor="#0099cc"
          android:endColor="#d1186b"
          android:startColor="#d1186b"
          android:type="sweep" />
     </shape>
</item>
```